# Download Bloomberg content

Tags: curl, wget

Is it possible to programmatically download Bloomberg content, for example:

Full Show: Bloomberg Technology (05/19)

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2017-05-19/full-show-bloomberg-technology-05-19-video

I would like to get the video via `wget` or `curl`, i.e. How I do that?

I tried to right-click the video frame to get the url, where I find

blob:https://www.bloomberg.com/843977a9-8ab1-4c37-9f1a-7cd5c1c0d734

But `curl blob:https://www.bloomberg.com/843977a9-8ab1-4c37-9f1a-7cd5c1c0d734` returns:

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'blob:https'

Comment: There are only two possible answers to your question: yes, or no. Somehow, I don't think that's what you are after. Please expand your question to... well... ask the **actual** issue you are facing, given that you have tried and failed with the above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click, inspect (on Google Chrome for example), then click network at the bottom, and preserve log and reload the page, then look through the names for the mp4 that it pulls and then look at the headers section. When I go to your link and follow that trail, I get

https://r3---sn-5ualdn7r.c.2mdn.net/videoplayback/id/347b0cc0011f0288/itag/37/source/doubleclick_dmm/ratebypass/yes/acao/yes/ip/2600:6c58:4280:373:f9b5:368:47ed:8a70/ipbits/0/expire/3635104080/sparams/acao,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,usequic/signature/638EF62FD9F1050B77181C43CC214EF8797DA5F2.61639EE4D795374EF15C0A139BCCEB570352463A/key/cms1/cms_redirect/yes/mm/42/mn/sn-5ualdn7r/ms/onc/mt/1495338185/mv/m/pl/32/usequic/no/file/file.mp4

Or additionally https://s-static.innovid.com/media/encoded/03_17/64465/2_source_41047_96563.mp4

Which takes you to just the mp4 file.

However, curl does not follow redirects by default. To tell curl to follow http redirects, add --location, like

```
curl --location <url> - with --follow
```

Comment: I tried curl on that mp4 but it does not return the video content. Could you provide more information, please?

Comment: @KcFnMi that url gives a `http 302 Found` redirect. and curl does not follow redirects by default. to tell curl to follow http redirects, add `--location`, like `curl --location <url>` - with --follow, i get the mp4 content here.